# datareceived Event Handler in Serial C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement the datarecieved based event handler, I think I am able to receive data from the port, but having difficulties executing the event.. I have tried both ReadLine and ReadExisting.. can you please comment on my code.. Thanks,

```
private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
              // graphing stuff
            portname = "COM1";
            parity = Parity.None;
            BaudRate = 115200;
            stopbits = StopBits.One;
            databits = 8;
            port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(portname);
            port.Parity = parity;
            port.BaudRate = BaudRate;
            port.StopBits = stopbits;
            port.DataBits = databits;
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
            port.Open();
            count = 0;
            }


    void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      try
        {
         line = port.ReadLine();
         count++;
         this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(LineReceived),line);
            }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          }
     }

  private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string text);

  private void LineReceived(string text)
  {

         if (zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Count <= 0)
             return;
         LineItem curve = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList[0] as LineItem;
         if (curve == null)
             return;
         IPointListEdit list = curve.Points as IPointListEdit;
         double value = double.Parse(text);
         list.Add(count, value);
        // graphing stuff
   }

// graphing stuff   
}
```

Comment: Keep the baudrate low.  You are invoking for one number at a time, that's a lot of invokes that can cause the UI thread to stop painting.  Your user can only see about 20 updates per second before it turns into a blur.  Buffer to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a lot of work with Serial communications, and `DataReceived` never works like I want it to. There is a property on `SerialPort` called `ReceivedBytesThreshold` that is supposed to change when the event fires, but I have hit and miss luck with it. Do some googling on this event, and you'll have thousands of results reporting problems with it. The event can work sometimes, but I wouldn't rely on it for mission critical operation.

The better way I have found to do it if you're looking for line endings is to simply have a tight loop that continually reads bytes into a buffer if they are available, and then invokes the `LineReceived` method on the buffer when it encounters a line ending. Put this on its own thread, and it should do the trick. Add a few `Thread.Sleep()` inside the loop to keep it from taking over.

If you're not looking for instantaneous reactions to the serial stream, then run it on a threaded timer every second or half second. Each tick of the timer, read all the existing bytes into the buffer, and whenever you encounter a line ending invoke `LineReceived`.

Comment: What problems did you have with DataReceived?  It's worked fine for me (I think I had ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1)

Comment: Sometimes, I have no issues at all. Other times, it simply refuses to fire when it should. I tend to have better luck when the data coming in is very intermittent (and the baud rate is slow). I think it has something to do with the event handler not exiting before the next group of data comes in. But, I find doing it the manual way yields better results for me on average.

Comment: Ok.. I just fixed a couple of problems and it seems to work but not as expected..(my declaration of the delegate was after i called it!) Some of the data was not being recognized as a double by double.Parse, but i have taken extra care on other end that what is being sent are double's with a linefeed! Anyway, i did float.tryparse and it seems to be working so that a relief, however, I know that I am not getting all of them.. this work will be somewhat critical when its done so I need to consider what drharris has suggested..

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the DataReceived event with great success in one of our products.  The protocol I am implementing mandates a minimum packet size of 6 bytes, so I use that are my receive threshold.

I make sure to keep any orphaned data, and reconstruct it the next time the event occurs if I get an incomplete read or a malformed packet.  I really have had very few issues with this implementation.  I would suggest locking in the event handler so you don't end up with a race on the serial port, but that may not be needed.