# DataReceived EventHandler works only once

Tags: c#

I am new to stackoverflow. I am having a problem with VC# Serial Communication. I need t receive data conyinuously from serial port but my code works only once. That is if I send "This is a Serial Comm Project". The data is received as expected but if I send the data again it doesn't work. Please provide a solution.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        mySerialPort.PortName = cbxCOMPort.Text;
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = int.Parse(cbxBaudrate.Text);
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
        mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = int.Parse(cbxTimeout.Text);
        mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 2000;
        mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
        mySerialPort.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
        mySerialPort.NewLine = "\r\n";
        mySerialPort.ReadBufferSize = 512;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;

        mySerialPort.Open();

        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        gbxMsgDel.Enabled = true;

}

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{// Event for receiving data

        // Read the buffer to text box.

        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DoUpdate));

}

private void DoUpdate(object s, EventArgs e)
{
        receivedMessage += mySerialPort.ReadExisting();

}
```

receivedMessage is a private string type. It is private to the class.

Comment: May be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380941/datareceived-event-handler-in-serial-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: It might be a better idea to `ReadExisting` as soon as possible, at the beginning of the event handler, and then pass the data to your invoked `DoUpdate` method. I have no idea if that will help in any way, but it means that you're separating the I/O operations from the UI, which may very well be running on a different thread. I wouldn't bet on `SerialPort` being thread-safe.

Comment: Hi Alex, please provide an example. I can't call DoUpdate() from inside DoUpdate() after reading data once because it will be calling DoUpdate(0 inside DoUpdate()

Comment: Using Invoke() in DataReceived is always a good way to cause deadlock, don't press button2.  And a Baudrate of 9600 is enough to pummel the UI thread to death when you invoke for every single byte you receive.  The snippet is otherwise totally inadequate to guess at the problem.

Comment: Hi Hans, I am doing a SMS receive application. The GSM Wavecom modem is configured to notify about new messages by sending +CMTI: "SM',x. When this data is received then the value of x is extracted and converted to int and used as message index that is to be read. Then I send "AT\r\n", "AT+CMGF=1\r\n", AT+CMGR= + msgIndex.ToString + "\r\n" commands to GSM modem one by one. I wait for response for each AT command before sending next. And my modem gives only "OK" as response for every successful command. That is all the code I have in my DoUpdate() function. The problem is after receiving new

Comment: message notification my app is displaying the Message (SMS) properly but only one time.If it receives another SMS it hangs.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before...

From MSDN

> "The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte
>   received"

One option is to use a timer to check available data instead of the event, something like this:

```
private void checkPortDataTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //You may want to check available bytes instead of this.
    string recievedData = comPort.ReadExisting();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(recievedData))
        someTextBox.Text += recievedData;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Are you telling me not to use DataReceived EventHandler? I see you have used Timer. Please provide full code and also tell how to use it so that it displays data whenever new data is received and also it has to run till the application is closed. In my code it receives data till it exits DoUpdate() function. I am reading data 5 times in  DoUpdate() and after it reads 5 different data then it exits DoUpdate() and it doesn't read data again. I need to click the button_1 again to make it read.